# Not pickup record if already picked up, Laravel 5.7 (Quiz System)

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, controller

I am making a quiz system in **Laravel 5.7** and now i'm fetching questions from the database and I have to apply the condition that if a user attempted a question then not show that question to the user again, for this I have made a database named as `attempted_questions` and two fields in there as `user_id` and `question_id` and applied the following code in controller:

```
class NewTestController extends Controller
{
    protected $question_id;
    public function nextQuestion(Request $request) {
        $attempted_questions = new AttemptedQuestion;
        $attempted_questions->user_id = Auth::id();
        $attempted_questions->question_id = $request->attempted;
        $attempted_questions->save();
        $question = Question::inRandomOrder()->first();
        $attempted = AttemptedQuestion::all();
        foreach ($attempted as $attempted) {
            while ($question->id == $attempted->question_id) {
                $question = Question::inRandomOrder()->first();
                $this->question_id = $question->id;
            }
        }
        return $this->question_id;
    }
}
```

Here first I'm getting attempted question from AJAX and then storing the current user and question_id in database and after that I'm getting random questions from database and after that checking if the taken question is already in database? if no then show it otherwise display a message, ***but the problem here is that it fetches the question also which is already taken***

Comment: shouldn't this condition be  while ($question->id != $attempted->question_id) { .

Comment: no bro here i'm checking that if the question which is taken is already in attempted questions db? if yes then take question from db again otherwise not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some logic error, You are taking a new random question in while loop while escaping the preceding attempted questions, here is what I mean:

Suppose you have 3 questions [1,2,3], and 2 attempted questions [1, 2].

So in your `foreach` loop you loop on [1, 2], now you are on the first attempted question which has `question_id` of 1, at this point you are taking a new question let's say its `question_id` is 2. then goes to the next iteration, the second `attempted_question` which has the `question_id` of 2.

here you compare the last result with current `attempted_question`, and it's equal so it satisfy the condition `$question->id == $attempted->question_id` so you are picking a new question and by chance you got the the question id of 1. at this point you are not going to check if it's equal to the first `attempted_question` because we already skipped it from the `$attempted_questions` array.

---

a better solution would be as follows:

take all `attempted_questions` id and use `whereNotIn` to get all questions that has not been attempted.

```
$attempted = AttemptedQuestion::pluck('question_id');
$question = Question::whereNotIn('id', $attempted)->inRandomOrder()->first();
```

now you have the question you are looking for.

But you are escaping if the current user has attempted to answer it or not, so you may have to add some `where` statements for `AttemptedQuestion` for the current user as follows:

```
$attempted = AttemptedQuestion::where('user_id', Auth::id())->pluck('question_id');
```

---

So you may end up with something like this:

```
class NewTestController extends Controller
{
    public function nextQuestion(Request $request) {
        $attempted_questions = new AttemptedQuestion;
        $attempted_questions->user_id = Auth::id();
        $attempted_questions->question_id = $request->attempted;
        $attempted_questions->save();
        $attempted = AttemptedQuestion::where('user_id', Auth::id())->pluck('question_id');
        $question = Question::whereNotIn('id', $attempted)->inRandomOrder()->first();

        return $question->id;
    }
}
```

But it's not tested.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks bro, but I'm a little bit mixed up can you edited mine code?

Comment: p.s you may check if `$question==null` and return some message to the user like "There are no more questions, please come back later" or so.

Comment: OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG!!!!!! Love you brooooooooooooo thankssssssss it's working like a charmm thanks again ❤❤❤❤

Comment: glad it helps ^^

Comment: Acutally this is a pretty bad solution. Because it fetches all the ids of the attempted questions. So when a user has answered a loot of questions this won't scale... Se my answer for an updated version

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the following solution:

```
Question::whereDoestHave('attempts', function($query) {
     $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
})->inRandomOrder()->take(1)->get();
```

This will work if you have defined the following in your Question-model:

```
public function attempts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\AttemptedQuestion');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you havewto ignore the id of the current cuestion in the model Question, also i cant see it i guess like that

```
1
```

'Question' => ['required', 'description', Rule::unique('user')->ignore($question->id)]

**hope that it helps!**